# Relative position: stick to bottom

Tags: html, css, position

I have a div with the positon set to `relative`. 
But I want that div to stick to the bottom of the screen, so it stays there, even if you scroll. I can't change the position to `fixed`, because it is necessary for the contents of said div.

Comment: why don't you try with `position:fixed; bottom:0;`

Comment: Set the parent to `position:relative;`, then set the child to `position:absolute; bottom:0;`

Comment: Yes you can :) `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` acts the same as `position:relative` on children elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parent to `position: fixed;` and stick it to the bottom, that way you don't need to change that `div` `position` property.

```
 # Example
.child { position: relative; }
.parent { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; }
```